# Apirtc voice call regarding issue in ionic app

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, call, phone-call

We are trying to implement apirtc audio and video call in our ionic application.

Video call working fine for us. While trying to use audio call feature there is small issue that, when a call is connected its default sound is on 'loudspeaker' , we want to set it as 'earpiece' that is without loudspeaker.

Is there any solution that we can overcome this problem?

Thank you in advance!

We have checked official document of apirtc(https://apirtc.github.io/references/apirtc-js/) , but found nothing related to turn ON or OFF loudspeaker.

Answer (score 0):

More than turning on / off certain output, I d have a look on how to change the stream's destination.

In general regarding ApiRTC Js implementation:

- There is no audio output selector embedded natively into ApiRTC
- The AudioOutput Devices APIs is still an emerging standard at the W3C (meaning it is not uniformly implemented across the main browsers) https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-output/
- Chrome implements the audio output selection already as per the demo here https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/multi/ using the setSinkId method on each of the HTMLVideoElements playing the incoming WebRTC streams

Nothing specific on Ionic though

Cheers,